# How to make span to change date value format according to date type?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, razor, luxon

I have a list of jobs, where when clicked a dialog box will open displaying the details along with job start date and end date. The browser only allows this format for the date 'mm/dd/yyyy', so to fix that I placed a span overlayed on it where it takes date input and converts it to the correct format and placed on the span to display. There are two problems, one is that sometimes the overlay span does not display the value of the date input, and instead goes into the default, 'dd/mm/yyyy'. And second is that, once the first problem is solved when another job is clicked for its details, the span is still showing the date of the previous job. Here is my code:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var DateTime = luxon.DateTime;

  $(function() {
    if ($("#txtStartDate").val() !== "") {
      var dateVal = DateTime.fromFormat($("#txtStartDate").val(), 'yyyy-LL-dd');
      $("#txtStartDate").parent().find("span").html(dateVal.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'));
    }

    $("#txtStartDate").bind('change', function() {
      if ($("#txtStartDate").val() != "") {
        var inputDateVal = $(this).val();
        var dateVal = DateTime.fromFormat(inputDateVal, 'yyyy-LL-dd');
        $(this).parent().find("span").html(dateVal.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'));
      } else {
        $(this).parent().find("span").html('dd/mm/yyyy');
      }
    });

    if ($("#txtEndDate").val() !== "") {
      var dateVal = DateTime.fromFormat($("#txtEndDate").val(), 'yyyy-LL-dd');
      $("#txtEndDate").parent().find("span").html(dateVal.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'));
    }

    $("#txtEndDate").bind('change', function() {
      if ($("#txtEndDate").val() != "") {
        var inputDateVal = $(this).val();
        var dateVal = DateTime.fromFormat(inputDateVal, 'yyyy-LL-dd');
        $(this).parent().find("span").html(dateVal.toFormat('dd/MM/yyyy'));
      } else {
        $(this).parent().find("span").html('dd/mm/yyyy');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.1/luxon.min.js"></script>

 

<table> 
  <tr> 
    <td style=" border-top-color:White; border-bottom-color:White"></td> 
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#e8eef4"> 
      Start Date 
    </td> 
    <td> 
      <div class="datepick"> 
        <input id="txtStartDate" name="startDate" type="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy" /> 
        <span class="spanDate">dd/mm/yyyy</span> 
      </div> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
 
  <tr> 
    <td style=" border-top-color:White; border-bottom-color:White"></td> 
    <td style="width:100px;background-color:#e8eef4"> 
      End Date 
    </td> 
    <td> 
      <div class="datepick"> 
        <input id="txtEndDate" name="endDate" type="date" value="dd/mm/yyyy" /> 
        <span class="spanDate">dd/mm/yyyy</span> 
      </div> 
    </td> 
  </tr> 
</table>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please replace the HTML with RENDERED HTML to make a [mcve]